# Replace Copy/Select popover when selecting text in UITextView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitextview

Is it possible to replace Copy/Select popover when selecting text in UITextView?
When text is selected, I want my own view to pop over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You can trap the request
- (BOOL) canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender

and there you return NO to everything and show your custom view.